# Clear a list and free up the system memory in scilab

Tags: scilab

So I am using scilab to analyze the image, here is a part of my code:

```
stacksize('max');
A = imread(file);
A_Gray = RGB2Gray(A);
Invert = ~A_Gray;
Thresh = CalculateOtsuThreshold(Invert);
LogicalIm = SegmentByThreshold(Invert, Thresh);
ObjectIm = SearchBlobs(LogicalIm);
Is = CreateFeatureStruct(%t);
Q = AnalyzeBlobs(ObjectIm,Is);
```

when I use AnalyzeBlobs I get a list which is in Q. this variable Q is soo big that it takes almost 2 GBytes of ram everytime I run the code. so I used All the stupid ways to clear this Q. by using the following functions

```
clear Q
clearglobal
```

even I did this:

```
for i=1:length(Q)
Q(i) = null();
end
```

the result is it clears the variable Q but the numbers inside are there and it doesnt get deleted. it is like it just delets the address of Q but not inside of it. this leads to a big issue and I have to restart scilab all the time.

is there any solution?

Comment: dirty hack from some forum, but you could shrink the stacksize and enlarge it again with `stacksize("min")` and `stacksize("max")`

Comment: @user1149326 this is not the problem of stacksize. when I check my memory usage from "system monitor" it shows 2.0 gb usage and by deleting all the variables it is still there. reducing the stack size wont change it either

Comment: And you are certain it is `Q`? When not calling `AnalyzeBlobs` the memory does not get out of hand?

Comment: yes @user1149326, it is exactly Q, if I dont call AnalyzeBlobs it doesnt increse memory

Comment: Reading the [comments on the IPD toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPD/8.3) there seems to be a memory leak in `AnalyzeBlobs`, maybe you're seeing the same leak?